# Concave approximation and error

Tags: functions, optimization, convex-analysis

How can I estimate an upper bound of the following difference : $$ \log \left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)-\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log (x_i), $$ where $x_i \in [1,2]$ and $n=10^6$

Comment: The exponential of such a difference is the ratio between the arithmetic and geometric mean of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Is the variance of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ or $\sqrt{x_1},\ldots,\sqrt{x_n}$ known?

Comment: To be more precise, we don't the variance in our sample. The quantities $x_i$ are estimated using a machine learning process.
The only thing we know (and we want) is that 0.4% of them are close to 2 and the rest is close to 1 (in other words 99.6% of the estimated values).

Comment: Okey, I agree with your last comment. Thank you for your help. But I Wonder if it exists a way to give an expression of the upper of the difference. An upper bound that depends on the value of $x_i$ or, in the worst case, of the proportion of value that are equal to 2, let say $\alpha$. Thank you.

Comment: I've found an upper that can be of the form : $$ \alpha\cdot \left(1-\log(2)\right) $$

Answer (score 0):

Be $m$ the number of $1$, $n-m$ the number of $2$.

Be $x:=\frac{m}{n}$ (therefore e.g. $m=\lfloor x\cdot n\rfloor$ for approximation).

One gets as a condition for the maximum $(\ln(2-x)-(1-x)\ln 2)'=0$.

Therefore $m=\lfloor (2-\frac{1}{\ln 2})n\rfloor$.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you trying to say. What i wanted is to know if we can give an expression of the upper bound of the différence, that depends on the value of $x_i$ which are continuous and belongs in  [0,1].

Comment: @Guillaume69: You have an approximation for an upper bound with $\ln(2-x)-(1-x)\ln 2$ and $x=2-\frac{1}{\ln 2}$. It's about $0,05966$.